# Swift: "invalid unicode scalar" error when using unicode code point as String literal

Tags: unicode, swift3

I am getting an "invalid unicode scalar" error when I try to include an Unicode code point in my String literal:

```
let str1 = "\u{127881}"
```

This is actually a valid code point for the  emoji.

Why am I getting the error and how can I include the `127881` Unicode code point in my String literal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a hexadecimal code, which is `1f389` in this case.

```
let str1 = "\u{1f389}"
```

But since this is Swift we are talking about, you can easily do this:

```
let str1 = ""
```